# Matlab: Efficiently Generating Subarrays from an array

Tags: performance, matlab, matrix, vectorization, matrix-indexing

I have an `m x m` matrix `M` that I am sampling different parts of to generate `k` sub-arrays into an `n x n x k` matrix `N`. What I am wondering is: can this be done efficiently without a for loop?

**Here is a simple example:**

```
M = [1:10]'*[1:10];                 %//' Large Matrix
indxs = [1 2;2 1;2 2];
N = zeros(4,4,3);                   %// Matrix to contain subarrays

for i=1:3,
   N(:,:,i) = M(3-indxs(i,1):6-indxs(i,1),3-indxs(i,2):6-indxs(i,2));
end
```

In my actual code, matrices `M` and `N` are fairly large and this operation is looped over thousands of times, so this inefficiency is taking a significant toll on the run-time.

Comment: you can use parfor (which runs parallel on gpu) to maximize speed but i think there is no way to not using for loop.

Answer (score 1):

It can be vectorized using [`bsxfun`](http://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/bsxfun.html) twice. That doesn't mean it's necessarily more efficient, though:

```
M = [1:10].'*[1:10]; %'// Large Matrix
indxs = [1 2;2 1;2 2];

r = size(M,1);
ind = bsxfun(@plus, (3:6).', ((3:6)-1)*r); %'// "3" and "6" as per your example
N = M(bsxfun(@minus, ind, reshape(indxs(:,1)+indxs(:,2)*r, 1,1,[])));
```

Comment: Had the same thing done at my end, but with two `bsxfun(@plus..)` instead for almost the same performance.